# Get the data between previous 11 months till current month using SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008, bigint

Help me with the below question.

I have ordermonth which is in BigInt format starting from 201801 till 202912.
I need to get the records where ordermonth from last 11 months till current month.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please tag your question for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions with a bit of arithmetic

```
WHERE ordermonth >= YEAR(DATEADD(month, -11, GETDATE())) * 100 + MONTH(DATEADD(month, -11, GETDATE()))
  AND ordermonth <= YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100 + MONTH(GETDATE())
```

> I would advise you to store `ordermonth` as an actual date. You could store either the beginning or the end of the month (you can get that with `EOMONTH()`)